In a python project, when should you use __init__.py, __main__.py, and just normal .py?
Say I am making a pdf editor app with the following structure:
├── main.py
├──  drawing_functions/
├──  util/
├──  GUI/
└──  document_handling/

Each of these folders have a collection of python code, and more subfolders.
Now there are a few ways to architect this:

Each of the folders can have an __init__.py, and treat each folder as a module
Each of the folders can have their own main.py, e.g. GUI/gui_main.py
Each of the folders can have their own __main__.py
The root directory main.py could be __main__.py

But I am not sure how to make these architecture choices. When should you use __init__.py vs __main__.py? I know what they do, literally. __init__.py is for declaring regular packages and are immediately executed on load, __main__.py will allow you to execute from the command line with -m. But if you import GUI.gui_main then the contents will be executed just like as if you imported GUI with an __init__.py. It's also totally possible to architect a project without these. When should you be using them and when should you not?
